# using sscanf in C to turn a hex String into command arguments for bash

Tags: c, bash, hex

Trying to make a hex decoder in order to read arguments from a command line file, and I'm having problems in C with operating string functions easily. The purpose of my hex decoder is so I can take a hex string, for example '2d6c002d6100f757372', and turn it into a set of instructions for bash, in this case -l -a /usr. My problem, however, is with my current code I can only get each of the characters extracted from the string individually, so I end up having 10 characters that make no sense to the bash shell individually. What I would ideally like to have is

```
args[0] = binary_path
args[1] = "-l"
args[2] = "-a"
args[3] = "/usr"
args[4] = NULL
```

but I can't figure out how to group the strings together that occur before each of the 0x00s in my hex string. Here is the code I have so far for this problem:

```
int i = 0;
char *hexString = "2d6c002d6100f757372"
char *hexPtr = hexString;
unsigned int *result = calloc(strlen(hexString)/2 + 1, sizeof *result);

while (sscanf(hexPtr, "%02x", &result[i++])) {
    hexPtr += 2;
    if (hexPtr >= hexString + strlen(hexString)) 
       break;


return result;}
```

Comment: Why do you need sscanf to convert a known hex sring inro int? `int hexToDec(int a) { return '0' <= a && a <= '9' ? a - '0' : a - 'a'; } ` and then `for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(hexSring); i += 2) { result[i/2] = hexToDec(hexString[i]) * 16 + hexToDec(hexString[i + 1]); }`

Comment: BTW the example hex string should be `2d6c002d61002f757372`, not `2d6c002d6100f757372`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Your `hexToDec()` is flawed. `int hexToDec(int a) { return '0' <= a && a <= '9' ? a - '0' : /* --> */ 10 + /* <-- */ a - 'a'; }`

Comment: Yeah but I want the strings to be their own arguments, because if I use other methods  I get -l-a/usr and it doesn't work in bash, thats why i'm trying to use sscanf

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int hex2dec(int value) // used to convert a hex digit to decimal
{
    if (isdigit(value))
        return value - '0';

    value = toupper(value); // to make the function more robust for various input
    if ('A' <= value && value <= 'F')
        return 10 + value - 'A';

    return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    char const *hex_str = "2d6c002d61002f757372";
    size_t hex_str_len = strlen(hex_str);

    size_t len = hex_str_len / 2; // there are half as many characters than hex digits
    char *str = calloc(len + 1, 1);
    size_t str_count = 1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        str[i] = hex2dec(hex_str[i * 2]) * 16 + hex2dec(hex_str[i * 2 + 1]);
        if (!str[i]) // at every 0-terminator
            ++str_count;  // count a new string
    }

    char **split_str = malloc(str_count * sizeof(char*));

    for (size_t i = 0, offset = 0; i < str_count; ++i) {
        size_t len = strlen(str + offset);
        split_str[i] = calloc(len + 1, 1);
        strcpy(split_str[i], str + offset);
        offset += len + 1;
    }

    free(str);

    // Output:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str_count; ++i)
        printf("\"%s\"\n", split_str[i]);

    // Cleanup:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str_count; ++i)
        free(split_str[i]);
    free(split_str);
}
```

#### Output:

```
"-l"
"-a"
"/usr"
```

Comment: how would i separate the strings in the answer?